# Deploying WSO2 in docker I'm unable to get to the Analytics Carbon page

Tags: docker, wso2, vmware, linux-containers

Deployed via the docker hub instructions to VMWare containers.

https://github.com/wso2/docker-ei/tree/master/dockerfiles/alpine

When accessing https://dockerhost:9444/carbon I get the following error:
Problem accessing: /carbon. Reason: Not Found

I re-deployed the Analytics worker container but that did not change anything.

Any help would would be excellent.  Trying to get this working in the next day or two.

Comment: I assume you are using the new wso2ei (6.X.X) version, the analytics is based on wso2sp (v 4.2+), there is no carbon console. You have to run separate containers for a worker (processing) and for dashboard (having url `https://dockerhost:9643/portal/`)

Comment: Yea I can get into that.  The issue is I cannot find the location to add users and change the admin password.  How would that be done?

Comment: you may have  a look https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/97565562

Comment: So there is no GUI interface to change passwords in Analytics?

Comment: Nope..  :( In theory - wso2sp can be connected to a key manager (wso2is?) according to the documentation. However I did not get it working yet..